# Can I combine explicit and "truly lazy" declarations in a SWIG interface file?

Tags: c++, swig

I have successfully wrapped a C++ library for C# using the "truly lazy" approach from the [SWIG tutorial](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html). It looks like this:

```
%module example
%{
/* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"
%}

/* Parse the header file to generate wrappers */
%include "header1.h"
%include "header2.h"
```

However, this doesn't expose all of the classes and methods I want. Can I somehow add explicit references to create the missing classes and methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All classes and methods should be exposed via the "truly lazy" method. If any are missing, something is wrong.

There are a number of potential causes. For example, the method/class may be defined in a different header, or you are mistaken about which headers you are including.

In my case it was because the class I wanted was actually a template, and SWIG doesn't generate templates. You must invoke the creation of a concrete class as follows:

```
%include "header1.h"
// defines List<T>, but doesn't generate List
%template(ListFloat) List<float>;
// now creates a concrete class called ListFloat,
// includes all the methods from that class
```

For more details see ["Templates"](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIGPlus_nn30) in the SWIG 3.0 manual.